# Почему не работает LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER?

Tags: android

Java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements LocationListener{
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,2000, 1, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String msg = "New Latitude: " + location.getLatitude()
                + "New Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps is turned off!! ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps is turned on!! ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Проверяю на эмуляторе. Если использовать GPS_Provider то работает. Но мне надо использовать только NETWORK_PROVIDER. Поэтому ACCESS_FINE_LOCATIONуказал.

Но ничего не работает. Что делать ребята????

Весь день уже на нервах. Ну что за люди эти Разработчики Гугловские((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь в манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Изменить:
    `requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,2000, 1, this);`

На: `requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,2000, 0, this);`

Comment: У меня и так ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: @xTIGRx, обновил ответ

Comment: Да хоть -100 все равно не заработает, я проверял. Вы откройте AS и попробуйте то что сказали)). Убедитесь в этом

Comment: @xTIGRx, на телефоне работает

Comment: А что за телефон у вас? на моем не пашет

Comment: @xTIGRx, на `Samsung Galaxy Ace` работает